# Angular+RestAPI design: estimating backend load

Tags: rest, angular2

I'd like to write an Angular2 application that consumes a REST API backend.
However I'm worried about the number of req/sec that such a request will generate, due to Angular "watches" or equivalent change detection algorithm

Should I limit from the beginning the watches (data binding? change detection algorithm?) to one big request per page, there other ways to deal with the problem in Angular or should I consider a different architecture from the beginning (eg. web sockets)

Comment: Did you mean Angular 1?   Watches don't exist in Angular 2 (It uses Zone.js instead); I would typically expect an HTTP Request from an Angular 2 app to be triggered from the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, which is called once when the component is loaded.

Comment: oh thanks you are right, my wrong, rephrased the question a little bit, no watches in Angular2, but I imagine that similarly any data binding must generate an API request. The application is like a dashboard, there is little UX/UI interaction but data shown should change dynamically, according to DB status....Anyway, I'm reading more about change detection in Angular2